# How to make it Short PHP?

Tags: php, regex, loops, foreach

i made a code like this and how to make it short ? i mean i don't want to use foreach all the time for regex match, thank you.

```
<?php
  preg_match_all('#<article [^>]*>(.*?)<\/article>#sim', $content, $article);

  foreach($article[1] as $posts) {
    preg_match_all('#<img class="images" [^>]*>#si', $posts, $matches);
    $img[] = $matches[0];
  }

  $result = array_filter($img);

  foreach($result as $res) {
    preg_match_all('#src="(.*?)" data-highres="(.*?)"#si', $res[0], $out);
    $final[] = array(
      'src' => $proxy.base64_encode($out[1][0]),
      'highres' => $proxy.base64_encode($out[2][0])
    );
?>
```

Comment: This kind of question is better ask at [codereview.se]

Comment: Use DOMDocument/DOMXPath and all your dreams will come true.

Comment: @Jens thank you for your answer, this is my first post.

Comment: If you changed your question to how can I achieve this (what do you want to extract) and a sample of the source XML, with this as your current attempt it would fit more to this site.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a robust code (that always works), avoid to parse html using regex, because html is more complicated and unpredictable than you think. Instead use build-in tools available for these particular tasks, i.e DOMxxx classes.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$state = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($content);
libxml_use_internal_errors($state);
$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);

$imgList = $xp->query('//article//img[@src][@data-highres]');

foreach($imgList as $img) {
    $final[] = [
        'src' => $proxy.base64_encode($img->getAttribute('src')),
        'highres' => $proxy.base64_encode($img->getAttribute('data-highres'))
    ];
}
```